# Magento - how to Retrieve products with a specific attribute value

Tags: magento, attributes, magento-1.7

at first iam new to magento..

I just wanna display the product values filtering with attributes

and I wanna run something like `www.somesite.com/something.php` and i should be able to see product details..

I already found some code for my doubt, but i didnt understood how to run that code as  `www.somesite.com/something.php`

pls suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use attribute filter to do so as follows on your collection :

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); //only enabled product
```

or

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('date' => true, 'to' => $fromDate)); //product created
```

etc

### Update

for example

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); //only enabled product
$collection->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); //add product attribute to be fetched
$collection->addStoreFilter();
```

Comment: May I know how to run your code in some php file? All I need is to enter some attribute value and I should get products having that attribute value...